# Embed page links dynamically in FB share button code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-core, razor

I have a dynamic list of profiles which have a static page link. I want to share that link to facebook but my static pages url not embedding in href of facebook code

Tried including link like this:
`href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=@Url.Content("~/"+@post.PostPageLink);src=sdkpreparse"` << Not Work
`href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=Url.Content("~/"+@post.PostPageLink);src=sdkpreparse"` << Not Work

```
@foreach (var post in profiles)
                                    { <div class="fb-share-button" data- 
href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button"
data-size="large"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={MyLinkShouldComeHere};src=sdkpreparse" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">Share</a></div>    
}
```

Result should be:

```
href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://localhost:44360/Uploads/Profiles/Pages/minal%2015_f0b7.html;src=sdkpreparse"
```

Comment: Can you please share what fields you profile model class has? I need to know post.PostPageLink is whether an absolute link or only name.html.  Because if post.PostPageLink is abolute link, then Url.Content is not needed.

Comment: post.PostPageLink doesn't contain absolute link, it has values like >> Uploads\Person\Pages\son 1_d78a.html

Comment: You can not properly share localhost links on Facebook. The URL needs to be publicly available, so that Facebook can request it and extract the Open Graph meta data.

Answer (score 0):

There is no curly braces needed inside your anchor tag.

You try this, *assuming that each post.PostPageLink is* **someName.html**:

```
    @foreach (var post in profiles)
    { 
       string pageUrl= Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority).ToString() + "/Uploads/Profiles/Pages/" + post.PostPageLink.ToString();

       <div  data-href="@pageUrl"  ... other attributes here ...   >
             <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=@pageUrl;src=sdkpreparse" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">Share</a>
       </div>

    }
```

If `post.PostPageLink` is an absolute link by itself, No Url.Content is needed:

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=@post.PostPageLink.ToString();src=sdkpreparse" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">Share</a>
```

**Note please:** According to the documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button), no `<a>` tag is needed. you may modify `pageUrl` variable above.